# calling REST service using Jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call a REST Service from my classic ASP application.
I heard that the best way to call a REST service is using Jquery.
Its not working for me. I dont know what mistake I am doing here .
Here is my code.

```
<script language="javascript" scr="inc\javascript\jquery-1.7.2.js" ></script>
 <script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
        CallService();
    });

                function CallService()
                {
                    alert("HelloWorld");
                    var Type = "POST";
                    var ServiceUrl = "http://mysite/restservice.svc";
                    var ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
                    var DataType = "xml"; 
                    var ProcessData = false; 

                    $.ajax({
                        type                : Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                        url                 : ServiceUrl, // Location of the service
                       //data               : varData, //Data sent to server
                        contentType         : ContentType, // content type sent to server
                        dataType            : DataType, //Expected data format from server
                        processdata         : ProcessData, //True or False
                       // success           : function(msg) {//On Successfull service call
                       // ServiceSucceeded(msg);                    
                        },
                        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
                    });
                }

</script>
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? What error are you getting? Please provide more detail to the question. Thanks!

Comment: What's the error, mate? Got any return values or console logs? I think we're going to need a bit more info.

Comment: Please describe what happens when you run that code, and why it is wrong. E.g., do you get a JS error? Do you get a server-side error? Does it appear to successfully reach the server but then not return? Or...? You've currently got the `data` commented out, so although that Ajax call should post to the specified url it isn't sending any data.

Comment: Did you include jquery?  Not jquery ui?

Comment: Hi thanks for all ur quick replies. Actually I am not getting any error. Page just loads fine and data is not POSTed to the site. I want to know whether my above code is right. Do I need to add any other code or need to inclue any AJAX libraries?

Answer (score 0):

A `<script>` tag with a `src` attribute won't get executed, only the references external script. So use

```
<script src="inc\javascript\jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="inc\javascript\jquery-ui-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
// your code here
</script>
```

Also, your script has a `scr` attribute, so jQuery won't get loaded but the content gets executed without jQuery available.

Comment: HI, I updated my code with ur code, still its not working. When I put a alert in the start of CallService() function , its not showing. Any idea what could be the problem.

Comment: What is in the both linked files? Are they both (at least jQuery "basics", your code doesn't need the UI plugin) loaded and executed properly? Do any errors show up (in the console)? Is `CallService` available in global scope (the indentation indicates there's a wrapper?)?

Comment: HI Bergi, please check my updated code. It seems the problem is with CallService() function. Its not even showing the Helloworld alert. I am using $.ajax in the function, do I need to copy any AJAX library or code related to AJAX? Remember I copied the above code from codeproject.com example

Comment: You still need to use *2* script tags, or have you updated that too? AJAX is included in the jQuery basic library. Maybe you could post a url to your site?

Comment: Hi Bergi, Yes I am using 2 script tags(question updated). Remember this project is in classic ASP. I am not able to debug the code either. Unfortunately there is url available at this time.

Comment: Why can't you debug the code? And when there is url available, please post it.